# Resources for data science applications in finance/banking

Tags: finance

What are good resources for data science applications in finance/banking ?

I want to know about the following:

- Trends in finance/banking area
- What creative companies do in finance/banking area with data science
- Major open data sources in finance/banking in Canada

I subscribed to several data science news but none of them focus on finance/banking. I need daily/weekly news and reports for my internship. This is my job and I will be evaluated based on this so it is very important for me to get enough information in time.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [O'Reilly free Ebooks](http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/) There are a couple of resources for banking/finance/fintech.

There are some sites from which you can work on for learning more about predictive modelling in this sector:

1.) https://inclass.kaggle.com/c/name-that-loan-open/data - Kaggle dataset   for prediction of interest rates

2.) https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/ - Dataset on Analytics Vidhya for loan prediction

3.) There is also a twitter handle with the name @StatCan_eng posting datasets related to Canada specifically.